# Huge gap between imageview and textview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, textview

On my activity with fragments, I've some pages that have an image and some that don't. The layout is like this: Textview-Imageview-Textview, so when I there isn't an image I want the Textviews to be below each other. This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#006400">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/handling"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/stilling"
        android:layout_below="@id/handling"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/arabisk"
                android:layout_below="@id/stilling"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textColor="#ff0000" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbdbK.png)

EDIT:

My array of images

```
int[] billede = new int[18];
        billede[1] = R.mipmap.sojle1;
        billede[2] = R.mipmap.sojle4;
        billede[3] = R.mipmap.sojle2;
        billede[4] = R.mipmap.sojle3;
        billede[6] = R.mipmap.sojle4;
        billede[8] = R.mipmap.sojle6;
        billede[10] = R.mipmap.sojle7;
        billede[12] = R.mipmap.sojle8;
        billede[15] = R.mipmap.sojle9;

        stilling.setImageResource(billede[mPage]);

        return view;
```

Comment: well you set a height for the imageview so what do you expect. if there is no image set the visibility to `GONE`

Comment: How do I do that in my array? (Have uploaded it) I can't write `billede[13] = stilling.GONE`

Comment: you set the imageview to gone not the bitmap

Comment: I tried it `android:visibility="gone"` but that removes all images

Comment: well duh, cause you set the visibility to gone, if you are looping through your images and displaying them you need to add logic to only display the image if there is one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the visiblity to `GONE`

in your xml

```
android:visibility="GONE"
```

or via code

```
imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: @Hudhud Because it is gone? If you are setting a src via code you have to set the visibility to `View.VISIBLE` again.

Comment: How to I do that? I can't say `if(billede[mPage] != null){
            stilling.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);             stilling.setImageResource(billede[mPage]); }` as operator `!=` cannot be applied to null/int

Comment: @Hudhud Beside the fact that you are trying to compare a primitive type to  an object, why do you even check that? As soon as you set a image src, make it visible........

Comment: Have fixed the problem. It was !=0

Answer (score 0):

Set ImageView visibility to Gone and your text view must be one below other like you want. Like this

```
stilling.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LinearLayout instead of `RelativeLayout`. And set visible View.GONE to hide `ImageView`.